# Determine Closed Form of Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a seemingly complicated recurrence relation for which I am having a hard time determining a closed form solution.

Given:
$d_0$, $u$, $c$, $s$

$d_n = d_{n-1} - u + c(\lceil \frac{s}{d_{n+1}} \rceil - 1)$

For clarity, this relation is for inventory management purposes.  I am using the ceiling function as all $d_n \gt \frac s2$ and when $d_{n+1} \lt s$, $d_n = d_{n-1} - u + c$.  Otherwise, if $d_{n+1} \gt s$, $d_n = d_{n-1} - u$.

Any help or direction towards getting to a closed form solution would be appreciated.  Also, I'm sure the main inhibitor to finding a closed form solution will be the ceiling function, so perhaps there is another approach that would lend itself better to this application--if so, I'm all ears.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a good chance there is no closed form...

Comment: @XTL - I realize this may be the case, and have already potentially resigned myself to this conclusion.  However, I know there are individuals out there much more skilled in math than I, so I'm holding out some hope.